# Use QTMovieView in Cocos2D Mac?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible?  I guess it is, but I can't figure it out.

So, the code for the movie thus far:

shrigString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"shrig_h264_720p" ofType:@"mov"];
        shrigURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:shrigString];
        //shrigMovie = [QTMovie movieWithFile:@"shrig_h264_720p.mov" error:nil];
        shrigMovie = [QTMovie movieWithURL:shrigURL error:nil];
        shrigMovieView = [QTMovieLayer layerWithMovie:shrigMovie];

```
    [[[[CCDirectorMac sharedDirector] openGLView] window] addChildWindow:shrigWindow ordered:NSWindowAbove];
    [shrigWindow setContentView:shrigNSView];
    [shrigNSView setLayer:shrigMovieView];
    shrigMovieView.frame = CGRectMake(size.width /2, size.height /2, 1024, 576);
    [shrigMovie autoplay];
    [shrigMovie play];

    NSLog(@"shrigMovie: %@", shrigMovie);
    NSLog(@"shrigMovie is: %@", QTStringFromTime([shrigMovie currentTime]));
```

However, I can't figure out how to ad that to my scene.  This is Cocos2D for Mac btw.

In the console:

shrigMovie is: 0:00:00:00.00/2500  So I guess it's loading ok, but simply not displaying?

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and spent quite a while trying to figure out how to solve it using QTMovie in combination with cocos2D. Eventually I gave up and started looking if there was a good existing solution to this. And voilà, I found **VideoPlayer**. Very easy to use and very lightweight, you can find it on https://github.com/psineur/CCVideoPlayer. Just be sure to copy only the necessary **VideoPlayer-folder** from the zip-file and don't forget the **CustomVideoView.nib** in the Resources folder. Add those to some lib-folder within your project, then you can start playing Video-files using those two lines:

```
[VideoPlayer setDelegate:self];
[VideoPlayer playMovieWithFile:@"intro.mov"];
```

You can then add the following delegate methods to your class

```
- (void) moviePlaybackFinished
{
}

- (void) movieStartsPlaying
{
}
```

Got it working in less than 10 minutes :)

Cheers